# Choosing specific python interpreter in the shell

Tags: python

I've been developing a set of scripts in PyCharm using C:/Python27/python.exe interpreter...

I'm creating a batch file and then running all of the scripts through this file from the cmd shell however the shell is not recognizing most modules because it is using the wrong interpreter (path for anaconda instead)...

How do I change the shell to use the C:/Python27/python.exe interpreter as default all the time instead?

I've tried looking this up but it all points to just adding the interpreter path, which I have... but the shell still uses the anaconda interpreter.

Any help appreicated

Comment: Have you a PYTHONHOME or PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem...

I needed to use:

set path=%path%;C:\Python27

This switched interpreter.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at : https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines

Shebang lines at the beginning of scripts tells how a script should be executed.

Comment: Are you sure that shebang lines can be used on Windows?

Comment: As of 3.3, with the launch of the Python launcher for windows, yes. The above link is a windows specific link for python.